# Adding divs inside an element through a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a draggable div(using jqueryui plugin for this) inside a table. I am able to drag a single div and keep it contained inside `<td id=” middle-side”></td>`. Now I am having issues trying to create additional divs that will be also be draggable and contained inside the `<td id=” middle-side”></td>`. The button I am using to append this new div is not reacting to the click. How would I be able to add new dragagble divs to  `<td id=” middle-side”></td>`? [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/2/)

Html

```
<td class="middle-side">
                Keep me inside here!
                    <div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
                        <p><b>Drag me around</b></p>
                    </div>

            </td>
```

Jquery

```
//To Drag
$(function() {
     $( ".draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
});


//To Add New Div
var i = 0;
var remove = true; // added this 
$('#button').click(function(e) {
    $('<div/>').attr({
        'id' : i
    }).addClass('draggale').css({
        'top' : e.pageY - 20,
        'left' : e.pageX - 20
    }).appendTo('.middle-side');
    i++;
});

$('.middle-side').on('click','.draggable',function (){ // corrected spelling
    if(remove){
        $(this).remove();
    } else {
        //just to see if it was clicked
        $(this).css({'background-color': 'red'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the div as a template in your .click function:

```
$('#button').click(function(e) {
    $('<div class="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"><p><b>Drag me around</b></p></div>').draggable({ containment: "parent" }).appendTo('.middle-side');
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/3/

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors in your code:

1. You misspelled `draggable`
2. You didn't re-bind all your `.draggable` divs

Here's the new code:

```
$('<div/>').attr({
        'id' : i
    }).addClass('draggable').css({ // Change CSS class
        'top' : e.pageY - 20,
        'left' : e.pageX - 20
    }).appendTo('.middle-side');
// Re-bind all your draggable divs
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
```

See Fidddle: http://jsfiddle.net/thejsj/0wbnud4k/7/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  $('.middle-side').append('<div class="draggable ui-widget-content"><p>text</p></div');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled draggable in one place, and also you have to re-initialize the draggable content after you add more of them.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0wbnud4k/4/)

```
$(function() {
     $( ".draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
});

var i = 0;
var remove = true; // added this 

$('#button').click(function(e) {
    $('<div/>').attr({
        'id' : i
    }).addClass('draggable').css({
        'top' : e.pageY - 20,
        'left' : e.pageX - 20
    }).appendTo('.middle-side');
    i++;
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
});

$('.middle-side').on('click','.draggable',function (){ // corrected spelling
    if(remove){
        $(this).remove();
    } else {
        //just to see if it was clicked
        $(this).css({'background-color': 'red'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have a typo in `.addClass('draggale')`, it should be `.addClass('draggable')`

Second you also have to call `.draggable()` on the new DIV to make it draggable

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwobhhnv/)